# Mongoose field with automatic document count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a Mongoose schema that contains a field that auto increments in the following format: `number-year`.
So for example, if I create 3 documents this year (2018) they should have that field with the values: `1-2018, 2-2018, 3-2018, ...`

I'm using the function `estimatedDocumentCount` to count the number of documents in the collection. This is a sample of my code:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;

var FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        match: /\d{1,}-\d{4}/,  // Code is in format nr-yyyy
        default: function() {
            return Foo.estimatedDocumentCount({})
                .then(count => `${count}-${(new Date()).getFullYear()}`)
                .catch(error => console.error(error))
        }
    }
});
var Foo = module.exports = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema);
```

Unfortunely, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Foo.estimatedDocumentCount is not a function
```

This is `package.json`:

```
"mongodb": "^2.2.33",
"mongoose": "^4.13.2",
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you, @Akrion but I don't understand your answer. I have no Order schema in my models. I just want a way to get the number of documents in this Schema, in order to set the default value

Comment: Edited the code, to make it more clear.
So, I need another schema just to count how many documents there are in my "Foo" model?

Comment: I thought that method was defined by mongo itself:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/

Comment: You are correct I was not aware of that method.

Comment: Try using `mongoose.model('Foo').estimatedDocumentCount().then ...`

Comment: I got a prromise pending error when i tried to save a new document when doing something ver similar -- any ideas.